Where do i get the email when a user requests to be a course creator in OpenEdx Tutor?
Can someone kindly tell that in Openedx Tutor, where do i receive the email after a user requests to be a course creator? I can see in the course creator section in the studio admin panel, there is the request present. but where do i receive the email of the request by the user?

You should set up "STUDIO_REQUEST_EMAIL" feature flag in the studio.
Depends on your installation method, ex: if it is the Tutor version then create a simple plugin for this.
